# Checking for near appearances of items in two lists - Python

Tags: python, list

I'm writing this function where I have two lists composed of '1' and '0' and for every occurrence of a '1' in list1, I have to check if there's any '1' in list2 at a given distance from the one in list1.

Here's the function I made so you can understand better:

```py
for i in range (len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == '1':
       if any ('1' == num for num in list2[i:i+distance+1]): 
          count += 1
```

I'm wondering if there's any faster way to do this or do something that starts with:

```py
for '1' in list1:
     if any etc.
```

Comment: 1) Make an index of list1 of the `'1'`s 2) then make a range index of the entries of `'1`'s in list2 3) compare the entries in the first index to the second. 4) Profit

Comment: sorry I don't understand could you explain more?

Comment: It's also helpful to put some inputs and outputs to make it clear.

Comment: You can't do `for 'i' in list1:`, did you mean `for i in (i for i in list1 if i == '1'):`?

Comment: @bogus If you are interested in performance, I would still suggest looking at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indexes = [i for i,d in enumerate(list1) if d=='1']
distance = 2
count = 0
for i in indexes:
    if '1' in list2[i:i+distance+1]:
        count += 1
```

This code is on average 1.5-2 times faster than yours. If we say about big array
Results + tests with answer upper
[Res image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKFQO.png)

Comment: Just what my comment described!

Comment: @dawg, Yes, the main thing is to find a quick method to get an array with indices. Maybe there is an even faster way.

Comment: `sum([tgt in list2[i:i+1+dist] for i in [i for i,e in enumerate(list1) if e==tgt]])`

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure my code is even more efficient (doesn't depend on distance). for example with `list1 = '0100110011' * 500000;
list2 = '1001100001' * 500000;
distance = 100000` my code runs at 7.11s (on my pc) while yours runs at 12.39 (because distance is big)

Comment: It is the same code more or less. You have `[i for i,d in enumerate(list1) if d=='1']` and I have `[i for i,e in enumerate(list1) if e==tgt]` to construct the index. You have `if '1' in list2[i:i+distance+1]: count+=1` and I have `tgt in list2[i:i+1+dist]` The only difference is the construction of a list with `[...]` which is fixed with `sum(tgt in list2[i:i+1+dist] for i in [x for x,e in enumerate(list1) if e==tgt])`

Comment: @dawg I wasn't talking about your suggestion, but about Alecs's answer, which is slower then mine in performance

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
ones = [i for i,d in enumerate(list1) if d == '1']
cur = 0 # cursor pointing to the current one-location of list2 in the list "ones"
count = 0

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if(list1[i] != '1'):
        continue

    # we will advance the cursor until it is past the lower bound of the selection
    while(cur < len(ones) and ones[cur] < i - distance):
        cur += 1
    # if the cursor is out of bound we know that there are no more ones we are interested in inside list2 so we can exit the loop:
    if(cur == len(ones)):
        break
    if(ones[cur] <= i + distance):
        count += 1
```

Note: this approach's performance only depends on the size of the lists and not on the distance variable

Comment: “This should work:” and “Sorry in advance for any mistakes.”  One solution to this caveat might be to *test* the answer before posting it?

Comment: @S3DEV by "This should work" I mean "This should work for you" but you are right, and I've tested it so I will update my answer